# How to use Field() macro of the GMock to match a nested member of a struct/union?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, match, googlemock

I have a struct that has a nested union, now I need to mock some method that takes a Message_t struct as parameter, and I want to match argument with specified value in a nested member of the union of the struct.

```
struct Message_t {
  enum MsgType_e { Empty = 0, Quote, Timer, Reqst, Reply, TYPE_COUNT };
  enum TdReply_e { Time_Out = 0, Stat_Chg, Settlmnt, Instrmnt, Commissn, REPLY_COUNT };

  MsgType_e   type;
  Period_e    period;
  union {
    struct {
      Contract_t* pContract;
      int         buff_used;
    } asQuoteMsg;

    struct {
      SysTimeNS_t now_time;
      AS2C_t      sec2clos;
    } asTimerMsg;

    struct {
      TdSession_t*   pTdSes;
      TdReply_e      reply;
      int            req_id;
    } asReplyMsg;
  };
};
```

With GMock, I want to do as following:

```
  EXPECT_CALL( someMock, notify( Field( &Message_t::asReplyMsg::reply, Message_t::Settlmnt ) ) ).Times( 1 );
```

But it can NOT be compiled.

How should I do? or I can NOT do it in this way?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to use field matcher to match unions. You can try to define your own MATCHER_P but this requires more boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been doing so.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, could you save us here and confirm if there's no way to match unions with `Field`?